# Search only particular index

Tags: apache, solr

I am using Apache Solr for my search , using this i am indexing variety of resources such as (PDF,MS Word document).

If let say the user giving the query like "PDF: java" then i wants to search only the PDF files

Any ideas

Thanks

Dilip.

Comment: Add a file_type field at upload time. So your filetype:pdf will work okay. If each document was identified by filename, query as id:*.pdf which returns results ending in only .pdf .

Comment: Any suggestions , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like I commented. Set up a filetype[string] in your schema and set it when you upload that file.

> http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=123&literal.filetype=pdf

and when you search

> http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=text:electrical design AND filetype:pdf

---

Quick hack: if your **documents are identified by filename**, you can tell Solr to limit results to those ending in *.pdf by

> http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=text:electrical design AND id:*.pdf